# Overlay an image on a background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm wondering how to create a new UIImage by overlaying one image overtop of another image?

What I'm doing is downloading an image from a web service. I'd then like to place this image over top of a background image (the background image is slightly taller/wider than the downloaded image). I'd then like to use this new image for the image of an annotation view on a map, so I need to create one UIImage from the downloaded image and the background.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programatically put one image data over (drawn above) another image,  and get the composite as a new UIImage:

[overlap one image over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993388/overlap-one-image-over-another/6993611#6993611)

Comment: Weird.. I searched for quite a while and didn't find that post. Thanks though - exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIImage object to store the image data that you downloaded. 
Use the constructor `[UIImage imageWithData:data]` for that.

Create a new UIImageView object.

Assign the UIImage object to the views' image property. You could do that in one go.

```
UIImageView *newImageView = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

(assuming that `data` is of `NSData` and contains the received data)

Then set the frame of your newImageView properly in the coordinate system of its superview and add it to its superview or vice versa.

Comment: I could do that if I was using image view's, but I need a single instance of a UIImage, not multiple image view's.